# Twitter Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I am trying to setup the Twitter gem, and I feel like I'm almost there... kind of.

Right now I was trying to follow this link:
http://www.phyowaiwin.com/how-to-download-and-display-twitter-feeds-for-new-year-resolution-using-ruby-on-rails

It is a bit old though, and I guess its instructions are a bit out of date. I have created a twitter model, twitter db migration and a twitter controller(not sure it's needed though), and if i open rails console, and I type:

```
Twitter.user_timeline("whatever").first.text
```

It just works. I just can't seem to be able to see it in my view. can you point me in the right direction?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex

In your controller that corresponds with your view, you need to assign your results to a variable inside the appropriate functionlike so:

```
def controller_function
  @twitter_data = Twitter.user_timeline("whatever").first.text
end
```

Then, in your corresponding view you can use the variable

```
<%= @twitter_data ... %>
```

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html for more guidance on controllers and views